# Do LLVM's arrays support 64-bit indices?

Tags: arrays, 64-bit, indexing, integer, llvm

The [LLVM assembly language reference manual](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#t_array) on arrays mentions "integer" here:

> The number of elements is a constant integer value; elementtype may be any type with a size.

While [integer is defined as](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#t_integer):

> The integer type is a very simple type that simply specifies an arbitrary bit width for the integer type desired. Any bit width from 1 bit to 2²³-1 (about 8 million) can be specified.

Does this work as easy as it sounds? Or do I have to consider something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When indexing a pointer using the `getelementptr` instruction, the index can be 64 bits (or whatever size). (Indexing steps that chose a particular field of a struct or vector must use an `i32`, however).

Comment: The answer is "yes". And, since a struct or vector could never have 4 billion members/elements requiring i32 in that case isn't a real restriction.